# Почему выдает ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня появилось желания устанавливать пакеты pip с помощью скрипта на Python. При этом у меня получилось сделать так что у меня работает, но на других ПК - нет. В начале идет установка, затем идет тест импорта, на котором и происходит ошибка.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

def InstallPackage():
  try:
    library = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    file = library.replace('Test.py', 'file.txt')
    print(f'[DEBUGGER] {library}')
    print(f'[DEBUGGER] {file}')
    os.system(f'cmd /c pip3 install -r {file}')
    return 0
  except:
    print('[DEBUGGER] An unknown error has occurred.')
    return 1
    pass

class ImportTesting:
  def sty():
    try:
      import sty
      return 0
    except ModuleNotFoundError as stderror:
      Template = '[DEBUGGER] An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}'
      ErrorMessage = Template.format(type(stderror).__name__, stderror.args)
      print(ErrorMessage)
      return 1

  def colorama():
    try:
      import colorama
      return 0
    except ModuleNotFoundError as stderror:
      Template = '[DEBUGGER] An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}'
      ErrorMessage = Template.format(type(stderror).__name__, stderror.args)
      print(ErrorMessage)
      return 1

def OutputTest():
  for i in range(91, 98):
    sys.stdout.write(fg(i) + 'Color Test \n' + rs.fg)
  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
  if not InstallPackage():
    if not ImportTesting.sty() and not ImportTesting.colorama():
      from sty import *
      import colorama
      colorama.init()
      OutputTest()

os.system("pause")
```

file.txt:

```
sty
colorama
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вот так инсталю:

```
    DEPS = ['sty', 'colorama']
    CMD = 'install ' + " ".join(DEPS)
    import pip
    pip.main(CMD.split())
```

Возможно на других компах pip3 не в PATH, а так сработает.

Похоже удалили функцию, тогда через subprocess

```
try:
    import colorama
except:
    import sys
    import subprocess
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'sty', 'colorama' ])
    import colorama
```

Comment: Ты - бог. Спасибо, сделаю в качестве еще 1 исключений твой вариант

Comment: Не работает. Пишет у pip нет атрибута main

Comment: ахах..) в прошлой версии был. вот смотрю убрали

Comment: @ПупкинВасилий добавил вариат

Comment: спасибо большое, я добавил твой вариант!